# How to render single quote in safe way

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I saw in a tutorial video that we should use Html.Encode in our views to prevent malicious injections.  However, when the text that I'm encoding contains the ' character (for example Dog's) the output in the browser is Dog#39;s. I would have thought every potentially dangerous character would be remaped to some safe code that the browser would render correctly.  Is this not the case?  How can I get ' to show up in the browser but in an HTML safe way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using ASP.NET MVC 2 <%: %> is already encoding the value for you
In Razor (MVC 3) @ encodes the values for you so you do not need to wrap the output in Html.Encode

Make sure that you are not double encoding

Answer (score 6):

The `@` in Razor automatically encodes for you, meaning that you probably did a double encode.
Example:

```
@Html.Encode("This is \"safe\"")
```

is more or less the same as

```
@{Response.Write(Html.Encode(Html.Encode("This is \"safe\"")));}
```

Dunno if that last one works in Razor though.

Comment: The last one would work in Razor, though you should not write directly to the `Response` object. If you do things might get rendered in an unexpected location.

Comment: The code runs sequentially, but razor output gets written to a text buffer which only gets flushed to the response stream once a page is finished executing. If you write to the Response stream directly then you might inject your output before the flushing occurs, thus resulting in unexpected ordering.

Comment: How do you get access (programatically) to the Razor text buffer? So that the example above could be changed so that it would always work?

Comment: in a Razor file the current buffer is available via `this.Output`.